# Why can't I make my button's width smaller?

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm working on universal app. When I'm designing the view for Windows Phone 8.1 project, I can't make any button's width smaller than 109. If I set the button's width property to smaller than that, it becomes 109 when rendered.

I would like to know how to force the button to be smaller than that, and why does this limitation exists in the first place.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are just dragging the button from the Toolbox, it will set a MinWidth and MinHeight for you.  You need to change these properties.

```XAML
<Button MinWidth="25" MinHeight="50" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I missed this simple thing. Too bad I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote the answer :(

Comment: @Telemat MinWidth allows for a minimum to be set when you are using a liquid width  e.g. dependant on dynamic content. Its pretty essential really.